# What CNC control board suits my needs?

Tags: usb, cnc-controller

I'm currently piecing together a shopping list to build an XY CNC (computer numerical control - basically computerized milling and production) machine. I'm looking at using this [motor kit](http://www.omc-stepperonline.com/3-axis-85nm1204ozin-nema-34-stepper-motor-ma860h-driverr-kit-for-cnc-router-p-306.html) that provides NEMA 34 stepper motors with drivers. Where I get confused is on what controls the drivers; I know I need a motion controller to control the stepper drivers, or at least that's what I've gathered. I'm only looking to feed the motion controller G-code commands from a custom application.

I'm looking for a stepper motion control board for the CNC machine that:

- can be controlled by sending G-code from a custom application
- accepts said G-code over a USB connection
- is compatible with NEMA 34 stepper motor drivers

For example, the [Tiny-G](https://www.synthetos.com/project/tinyg/) board is exactly what I'm looking for but only supports smaller motors as far as I can tell.